# How to combine two rows in Python list

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a 2D list,

```
a= [['a','b','c',1],
    ['a','b','d',2],
    ['a','e','d',3],
    ['a','e','c',4]]
```

I want to obtain a list such that if the first two elements in rows are identical, sum the fourth element, drop the third element and combine these rows together, like the following,

```
b = [['a','b',3],
     ['a','e',7]]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas`'s `groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.groupby([0, 1]).sum().reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
df.groupby([0, 1]).sum().reset_index().values.tolist()
Out[19]: [['a', 'b', 3L], ['a', 'e', 7L]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your list is already sorted, then you can use `itertools.groupby`. Once you group by the first two elements, you can use a generator expression to sum the 4th element and create your new lists.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> a= [['a','b','c',1],
        ['a','b','d',2],
        ['a','e','d',3],
        ['a','e','c',4]]
>>> [g[0] + [sum(i[3] for i in g[1])] for g in groupby(a, key = lambda i : i[:2])]
[['a', 'b', 3],
 ['a', 'e', 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas groupby methods to achieve that goal.

```
import pandas as pd

a= [['a','b','c',1],
    ['a','b','d',2],
    ['a','e','d',3],
    ['a','e','c',4]]

df  = pd.DataFrame(a)
df_sum = df.groupby([0,1])[3].sum().reset_index()
array_return = df_sum.values
list_return = array_return.tolist()
print(list_return)
```

list_reuturn is the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested. Here is an implementation using raw python. I've only tested it on the dataset you provided.

```
a= [['a','b','c',1],
['a','b','d',2],
['a','e','d',3],
['a','e','c',4]]

b_dict = {}
for row in a:
    key = (row[0], row[1])
    b_dict[key] = b_dict[key] + row[3] if key in b_dict else row[3]
b = [[key[0], key[1], value] for key, value in b_dict.iteritems()]
```